# asp.net OnClientClick window.location.href not working in google chrome

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web

Has somebody a hint why this peace of code isn't working in google chrome, but in every other browser?

```
buttonNeuerBeitrag.OnClientClick = String.Format("javascript: window.location.href='mailto:support@actosoft.de?subject={0}';",subject);
```

It should open the default e-mail client.

Answer (score 0):

Please give it a try with these:

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

or

```
window.location = 'url';
```

Comment: @kedritch What if you change the protocol to html something like http://www.google.com? Link is not working again?